# MVC4 Unit Of Work with Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, repository

I am designing a new asp.net MVC4 application. I know that context class generated by EF is Unit of work and Dbset is the repository class. I am just avoiding the extra abstraction. I want to know whether I am following the correct pattern or not.

### Entity

```
  public partial class ProductMaster
  {
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

  }
  public partial class CompanyMaster
  {
    public long ID{ get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
  }
```

### Context class(Generated By EF)

```
public partial class SampleEntities : DbContext,IUnitOfWork
{
    public SampleEntities()
        : base("name=SampleEntities")
    {
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
       SaveChanges();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<ProductMaster> ProductMaster { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyMaster> CompanyMaster { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserMaster> UserMaster{ get; set; }


    public virtual ObjectResult<SP_UserMaster_Result> SP_UserMaster(Nullable<long> tM_UM_ID, string userName, string userPassword, Nullable<byte> userType)
    {
        var tM_UM_IDParameter = tM_UM_ID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("TM_UM_ID", tM_UM_ID) :
            new ObjectParameter("TM_UM_ID", typeof(long));

        var userNameParameter = userName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserName", userName) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserName", typeof(string));

        var userPasswordParameter = userPassword != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserPassword", userPassword) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserPassword", typeof(string));

        var userTypeParameter = userType.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserType", userType) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserType", typeof(byte));



        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<SP_UserMaster_Result>("SP_UserMaster", tM_UM_IDParameter, userNameParameter, userPasswordParameter, userTypeParameter);
    }
}
```

### Unit of Work Interface

```
public Interface IUnitOfWork
{
    public DbSet<ProductMaster> ProductMaster;
    public DbSet<CompanyMaster> CompanyMaster;
    public Dbset<UserMaster> UserMaster;
    public virtual ObjectResult SP_UserMaster(Nullable<long> tM_UM_ID, string userName, string userPassword, Nullable<byte> userType){};
    public void Commit();
}
```

### Business Logic(Implementation)

```
 public class ProductMaster
 {
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public ProductMaster(IunitOfWork unitOfWork)//Injected using Ninject
    {
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    public void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        _unitofWork.ProductMaster.Add(product);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
 }
```

### Interface of Product Logic

```
 public class IProductMaster
  {
    public ProductMaster(IunitOfWork unitOfWork);
  }
```

### Product Controller

```
  public class ProductController : Controller
  {
     IProductMaster _productMaster;
     public ProductController(IproductMaster productMaster)
     {
       this._ProductMaster=productMaster;//Injecting using Ninject
     }
     public void SaveProduct(ProductMaster product)
     {
        this._productMaster.AddProduct(product.ToEntity());
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you’re starting with an implementation (Entity Framework) and then trying to bind this to two common design patterns – Unit Of Work and Repository.  The Entity Framework handles these two patterns and combines them together in Microsoft’s own implementation – they couldn’t actually work independently, for example you couldn’t just take a `DbSet` (Repository) and get a `Product` (entity) without instantiating the context (Unit Of Work).

These design patterns exist so they can be easily replaced within your application without changing much code, but if your `IUnitOfWork` is returning a `DbSet<T>` repository and you decide to read your `Product` entities from a local file instead of a database then you’re not really going to be able to implement this with your current abstraction.

1. `IUnitOfWork` should be strongly-named to the domain context – this is actually containing names of repositories which are specific to the domain context i.e. `ProductMaster`.  You could have `IShopUnitOfWork` derive from `IUnitOfWork` (which only has `Commit` as this is reusable in different domain contexts)
2. Your `IUnitOfWork` will get progressively bigger as you add new repositories and stored procedure definitions and I fear you’ll break the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) because of this.
3. I believe your repositories should actually contain the “query” calls specific for an aggregate root entity rather than your Unit Of Work – by putting it in the Unit Of Work you’re giving it two responsibilities:

i.  Maintaining the register of objects to be persisted

ii. Knowing how to authorise a user (in your example) along with all of the other stored procedure calls you’ll have

Therefore this will violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Furthermore `SP_UserMaster` should probably exist in the `User` repository as its specific to that domain entity.  Again this is strongly-named to imply a database call with a stored procedure – what if this was to be changed to a web service call?

With these caveats in mind it’s going to be hard to change your implementation to work this way with Entity Framework as Microsoft has taken the design patterns and implemented it in their own way with Unit Of Work and Repository mingled together - I'm not saying this is wrong its just the way they've decided to do it.  The main benefit of having these abstractions in this context is the benefit of being able to create stubs in unit testing so you’ll be mocking stored procedure and query calls without hitting the database.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick style remarks.

`Nullable<long>`: convention now is `long?`

---

There is a lot of repeated code like this:

```
 var userNameParameter = userName != null ?
    new ObjectParameter("UserName", userName) :
    new ObjectParameter("UserName", typeof(string));
```

Why not do this:

```
 var userNameParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserName", 
    (userName == null) ? typeof(string) : userName);
```

---

Can't you rename `tM_UM_ID`, `SP_UserMaster_Result`, `tM_UM_IDParameter`? These are ugly names that violate C# naming guidelines.

---

I get why you're naming things `userNameParameter`, `userPasswordParameter`,... but I feel that's the wrong approach. Instead I'd propose a single class that contains all of the necessary parameters, e.g. like this:

```
internal class StoredProcParameter
{
   public string UserName {get;set;}

   // other properties

   public List<ObjectParameter> ToObjectParameters()
   {
      return new List<ObjectParameter>
      {
         new ObjectParameter("UserName", 
                   (UserName == null) ? typeof(string) : UserName)
      };
   }
}
```

Then you could use that class, i.e; fill it with the necessary data, call `SP_UserMaster()` and pass that class as the param, and use the `ToObjectParameters()` method when you call `ExecuteFunction()`.

---

Your code also seems to be broken: in the last excerpt you have `this._ProductMaster` and there is no `_ProductMaster`. Moreover, since the `_` prefix indicates a field there should be no need for the `this.`.

---

Your comment style is inconsistent. I'd put the `//Injected using Ninject` on the line above the method, not next to it on the same line or below in the method's body. Also, is it even necessary?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.The variable names i wrote here is generated automatically by the entity framework(database first approach). The context class itself is auto generated. Actually i was asking about the design pattern i followed. Thank you for mentioning about the coding style problems